# std::async with a member function, holding another meber fucntion as an argument

Tags: c++, c++17, member, std-function, stdasync

I have the following class:

```
class Test
{
public:   
   void Func1(std::string const& a, std::string const& b, std::function<void(std::vector<double> const&, int)> func);   
   std::vector<double> Func2(std::vector<double> const& v, size_t const i);
};
```

To asynchronously call the function Func1 I did:

```
Test te;
auto fa = std::bind(&Test::Func2, &te, _1, _2);
auto fb = std::bind(&Test::Func1, &te, a, b, fa);
    
auto fab = std::async(std::launch::async, fb);
```

The 'fa' and 'fb' compiles but the async call 'fab' doesn't. How should I call the std::async for Func1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fa` and `fb` don't fully "compile" until you actually call them - the function call operators aren't instantiated till then, it seems. Once you call, you'll realize that `fb` is invalid, i.e. `fb()` won't compile. As soon as you fix that, the `async` call will work :)

As a further hint, observe that `std::bind` is subtly broken and not recommended for new code. You'd be better served with lambdas (they'd actually work here!).

How is bind broken? Like so:

```
std::bind(&Test::Func1, &te, a, b, fa)(); // won't compile
```

But:

```
using FnArg = std::function<void(std::vector<double> const&, int)>;
fb = std::bind(&Test::Func1, &te, a, b, FnArg(fa));
fb(); // compiles OK
```

So, you'd be best served by forgetting about `std::bind`'s existence, and use lambdas:

```
#include <functional>
#include <future>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Test
{
public:
    using FnArg = std::function<void(std::vector<double> const&, int)>;
    void Func1(std::string const&, std::string const&, FnArg) {}
    std::vector<double> Func2(std::vector<double> const&, size_t const) {}
};

int main()
{
    Test te;
    std::vector<double> vd;
    std::string a, b;
    auto fa = [&te](const auto &a, auto b){ return te.Func2(a, b); };
    auto fb = [=,&te](){ return te.Func1(a, b, fa); };
    fa(vd, 1);
    fb();
        
    auto fab = std::async(std::launch::async, fb);
    fab.wait();
}
```

Feel free to mess with it [online](https://onlinegdb.com/B1aa1UQqw).

Comment: Perfect, it works as I needed! Could you please elaborate, or provide a link, regarding your statement "std::bind is subtly broken and not recommended for new code"? Thanks.

Comment: What more evidence do you need that it's broken? It doesn't work! That's what your question is all about. You'd not be asking if it did work! You can pass given argument directly to a function and it'd accept it, but when you bind the same argument the resulting functor doesn't compile. That's how broken `std::bind` is. The expectation is that `std::bind` wraps a function call, so if `fun(a,b,c,d)` works then you'd hope that `std::bind(&fun, a, b, c, d)()` will work as well. And as you have demonstrated, it's not the case. Don't use it. It's broken :)